# PHP: Doctrine: order joined records

Tags: php, doctrine, left-join

I'm new to doctrine: I have a problem with the sorting of joined records.

A sample.

I've got an Article model which is associated with a Source model in 1 <-> n. The source model has a property called 'position' with an integer value.

Now I want to fetch an article with it's sources orderes by the position. My DQL looks like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('a.title, s.content')
  ->from('Article a')
  ->leftJoin('a.Source s')
  ->where('a.id = ?')
  ->orderBy('s.position');
```

The result doesn't change if I edit the position.

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: I have the same problem... still no solutin :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks OK. Try to generate the SQL from the DQL with [getSqlQuery()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en#join-syntax) and query the database with the result. If there is still the wrong output, it might by a problem with the data or more likely, with the DQL.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you should include the column that you are using for the ordering (s.position), so try this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('a.title, s.content, s.position')
->from('Article a')
->leftJoin('a.Source s')
->where('a.id = ?')
->orderBy('s.position');
```